# Python crashes instead of raising an exception

Tags: python, runtime-error

I wrote this program:

```
def fun():
 try: 1/0
 except: fun()
fun()
```

I thought that I will get an exception, but instead, I got the following fatal error:

```
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.

Current thread 0x00003bec (most recent call first):
File "<stdin>", line 2 in fun
File "<stdin>", line 3 in fun
```

(the `File "<stdin>", line 3 in fun` line is shown 98 times) and then the program crushes (instead of raising an exception).

I don't really get why this happens.
When I run the above program without errors it just raises an exception:

```
def fun():
 fun()
fun()
```

Raises the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in fun
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in fun
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in fun
  [Previous line repeated 995 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

But when the code is erroneous, the program just crashes.

Can anyone explain to me why this happens?

Comment: Yes. On failure you just repeat the call to the same function that just failed. It's a downward spiral of doom. Your exception handler should catch the error and do something different, not repeat the exact same process again. "Insanity is doing the same thing over and over again and expecting a different result"

Comment: @roganjosh Thank you. But please write answers in an answer instead of writing it in the comments, so people can vote it up or down.

Comment: You already have an answer that is more comprehensive than I can do on a phone. It makes the same point as me in different words, you are free to accept that. I didn't intend to write anything definitive here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you call your function within the function of the same name leading you down a rabbit hole of recursion (a function calling itself) with no escape

```
def fun():
 try: 1/0
 except: fun()
```

This means that when you call `fun()` if `1/0` raises an error it will move to the `except` branch and call the function fun which if `1/0` raises an error it will move to the `except` branch and call the function fun which if `1/0` raises an error it will move to the `except` branch and call the function fun which if `1/0` raises an error it will move to the `except` branch and call the function fun which...

If you get the picture.

So if it's error handling you are learning you might simple want to return some value like:

```
 def fun():
     try: 
         1/0
     except: 
         return "Error handling worked"

fun()
```